# Div and Text breaks up position whenever zoomed in or out or in different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to remake an old section of my website today, and with a little fiddling, I got it to look the way I wanted to, and I thought everything was fine, that is until someone pointed me that the text was out of place, so I zoomed in and out and noticed that zooming would break the position of the box, and the same would happen if you had any resolution other than mine

[image: Here's how it looks on my end/how it should look]

Here's how it looks on my end/how it should look

[image: Here's how it looks once zoomed in or out/on different resolutions]

Here's how it looks once zoomed in or out/on different resolutions

Here's my HTML code

```
<div>
<div class="DailyMessage">
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;">Today's Daily Message</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Don't beat yourself because of others</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Even if they're "family", because everyone around you</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">that cares and looks for you is your family</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Bloodline doesn't make a family.</p>
</div>

<div class="DailySong">
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;">Today's Daily Song Recommendation</p>
<a href="https://youtu.be/VSpgaN3wuag" target="_blank"><p style="color:green;font-size:115%;">ZAYN - Vibez</p></a>
</div>

<img src="images/DailySpeech.png">
</div>
```

And here's my CSS

```
  .DailyMessage {
  position: absolute;
  right: 44.50%;
  bottom: 5.50%;
  }

  div.DailyMessage {
  flex: 1;
  }

  .DailySong {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50.50%;
  bottom: -24%;
  }

  div.DailySong {
  flex: 1;
  }
```

Comment: why did you position absolute your .DailySong container? the behaviour you described wouldn't occur if you just had its content positioned as static (default value). But the code you included doesn't show the page layout and it's not clear why you had to use that absolute position strategy that of course would screw everything if the window isn't the same exact window you had when you tested it. Maybe you just meant to use padding instead of adjusting position relative to bottom and right.

Comment: I'm still very new to the whole positioning schtick, hence why I used the position: absolute;

If you want the layout for my whole page, just check the website itself https://junessai.net/

Comment: Oh yeah, I also used position: absolute; due to the fact that I couldn't place the text on the image in case I didn't use it.

Comment: now I see the problem you are having... your "speech bubble" is made with a picture and you are trying to display your text encased in that frame. It's a bad approach because you can't rely on the document flow for sizing and positioning and you are forced to use absolute offsets. It could still be achieved somehow if you put the picture inside the .DailySong container that you should style with `position:relative`. Then your paragraph should have `position:absolute;top:0;width: 100%;margin:auto;`  and account for a left offset like `left:-200px;`.

Comment: I got a good result as mentioned in the answer I posted, and now the text stays in the proper position I wanted, even on different resolutions, zooming doesn't seem to be a problem anymore either

Although I will try and look for your suggestion, since I feel the method I used really isn't optimal

Still, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, although I'm not sure how efficient it is when it comes to optimization

I've made a div and set the background to be the image I wanted, and then I set it's CSS properties to the ones below:

```
  .DailyStuff {
  background-image: url('images/DailySpeech.png');
  background-repeat: none;
  width: 852px;
  height: 325px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

  div.DailyStuff {
  flex: 1;
  }
```

And then, after creating this div, I then changed the position from absolute to relative, removed the flex: 1; property from the two other boxes, and positioned the boxes correctly with CSS

```
  .DailyMessage {
  position: relative;
  right: 164px;
  top: 21px;
  }

  .DailySong {
  position: relative;
  right: 166px;
  top: 184px;
  }
```

Here's the HTML aswell

```
<div class="DailyStuff">
<div class="DailyMessage">
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;">Today's Daily Message</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Don't beat yourself because of others</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Even if they're "family", because everyone around you</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">that cares and looks for you is your family</p>
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;">Bloodline doesn't make a family.</p>
</div>

<div class="DailySong">
<p style="color:black;font-size:115%;font-weight:bold;">Today's Daily Song Recommendation</p>
<a href="https://youtu.be/VSpgaN3wuag" target="_blank"><p style="color:green;font-size:115%;">ZAYN - Vibez</p></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And then, the clipping issue was fixed, and when looking at the new section with different resolutions, the text is now properly displayed, and zooming in doesn't break the position anymore, albeit zooming too much still makes the text shift a little, but not enough for it to be a huge problem

I still feel I could clean this code a little better, but as of now, it works, and that's all that matters

If anyone has any suggestions, opinions or criticism, either about the website or my code, I welcome it dearly.